# How we form a group from the subset $\{5,29,53,77\}$ of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{96}^*$ (extra challenge: $\{5,29,53,77,85\}$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{96}^*$ the multiplicative group modulo $96$ (the group of units).
The subset $\{5,29,53,77\}$ contains those integers that all have a remainder $5$ when divided by $24$.
What is a common way to form a group from this set - no matter what the operation is? (Preferably the group will be multiplicative.)

And (maybe a bit more difficult) what if we take the set $\{5,29,53,77, 85\}$?

Comment: How can you form a subgroup of $5$ elements of a group of order $32$?

Comment: Will it help if we must not stick to the modulus $96$? For me it does not matter what the new operation is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group must contain $1$, but just adding $1$ to the four-element set does not form a group because its order must divide that of $\mathbb Z_{96}^×$ which is $32$. Thus we repeatedly multiply elements together until closure is achieved, and get an $8$-element group $\{1,5,25,29,49,53,73,77\}$.

With an extra element $85$ we do the same operation and get a $16$-element group.